# Why won't my images load up from my java servlet?

Tags: javascript, java, python, servlets

I'm connecting to an IP Cam via python and running that script in a Java servlet. Then I am loading each image in Java and converting it into a byte array with base64 encoding. Lastly I ask for that data via AJAX through a JSON object. I don't receive any errors but the images don't appear either.

JavaScript:

```
$().ready(callToServer);
        function callToServer(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"DroneServlet.do",
                async:true,
                data: null,
                dataType:"json",
                success: drawImage,//function to do is success
                error: badRequest//function to do is error
            });
            setTimeout(callToServer,5000);
        }
        function toArray(str){
            var i;
            var bytes=[];
            for(i=0;i<str.length;i++)
            {
                bytes.push(str.charAt(i));
            }
            return bytes;
        }
        function badRequest(){
            console.log("failed");
        }
        function drawImage(json)
        {
            var img = json.imgData[0].imageToDisplay;
            var biStr=toArray(img);
            var data = biStr.join('');
            //var base64 = window.btoa(data);
            document.getElementById("dynamic").src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data;
        }
```

Java snippet:

```
    byte[] imgData = PythonRunner.grabPhotoBytes();//loads single image and convert to byte[]
    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject img = new JSONObject();
    String encodedImg = Base64.encodeBase64String(imgData);
    img.put("imageToDisplay", encodedImg);
    jsonArray.add(img);
    jsonResponse.put("imgData", jsonArray);
    out.println( jsonResponse.toJSONString()  ); // send the WeatherData collection in JSON format
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending image as Base64 would be worst thing here, you just get the image and save it on server local system using `ImageIO` class, and of course as a name(maybe random).

First you have the saved data as following, on server system

`/root/image_folks/trejon_house7222015-0342.jpeg`
where the name would be a random or anything.

Then response the image name by json response to the client as a simple string, and client will simply ask for `/get-image` cgi/servlet to get the image(like `/get-image?id=trejon_house7222015-0342`).

now have a simple servlet which loads the server local file and response it to the client, but don't forget to specify the MIME type